# T460s Ultra Dock not detecting three displays

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I have a T460s Lenovo with integrated skylake graphics. I just bought an Ultra Dock with 3 monitors connected to it. Everything works perfectly in Windows 10, but in Ubuntu 16.04, all three displays are mirrored. When in the display settings, it only recognizes one monitor. Any suggestions to get this dock working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stupid guys, I didn't see that "Mirror Displays" was checked.